# htaccess double rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm currently using this to redirect domain.com/username to the following address

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ publicprofile.php?username=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

I am developing a mobile site, therefore i need to redirect mobile users to mobile site.

this are the code i found for mobile redirecting

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPhone.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.yourdomain.com [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BlackBerry.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.yourdomain.com [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Palm.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.yourdomain.com [R=301]
```

how do i make both of them work at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Allow me optimize your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iphone|blackberry|palm|android) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.yourdomain.com [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ publicprofile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

[NC] stand for 'case insensitive'. [QSA] is to append the query string.
You can test your rules at [mod_rewrite tester](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/).

Comment: I'm a bit hypercritical with grammar probably, but `[NC]` stands for `No Case` not `case insensitive`.  They are synonyms, but when expanding an _acronym_ you usually want to be exact for the benefit of exhibiting what each character of the _acronym_ literally represents.

Comment: [`[NE]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6529394/712308) [also](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) maybe usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Put the second block before the first, and you should be good to go.

The second block will do header redirects if needed, which will cause a new request to happen. After that, the internal rewriting rules have their turn.