# mod_rewrite urlencoding an already urlencoded query string parameter - any way to disable this?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

We have some very basic mod_rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^something.swf$ http://www.newdomain.com/something.swf [R=302,L]
```

mod_rewrite seems to do its job, and if the user is accessing:

`something.swf?param=value`, it is redirected correctly to `http://www.newdomain.com/something.swf?param=value`

the problem is in this situation:

```
www.olddomain.com/something.swf?param=URL_ENCODED_VALUE
```

what ends up happening is mod_rewrite takes it upon it self to re-urlencode the query string param

so what the user ends up with is:

```
www.olddomain.com/something.swf?param=URL_ENCODED_VALUE
```

REDIRECTED TO

```
www.newdomain.com/something.swf?param=URL_ENCODED_VALUE_OF_URL_ENCODED_VALUE
```

so we end up with a double-urlencoded value. boourns!

While I do understand we could make a `\?(.*)` ... `?$1` rule for this, I am thinking there must be a way to tell mod_rewrite NOT to urlencode the query string params... we would like to avoid using 2 rules since valid paths are:

```
something.swf (no query string)
```

and

```
something.swf?someparams...
```

so yea, ideally... just tell mod_rewrite: please, no urlencoding of query string params... just direct passthru to the new URL via `R=302`.

Comment: doh! the answer is, the NE parameter. sorry!

Comment: Is bet it was. Can you provide an answer and mark it as accepted? (I guess there is a time limit to do that, but do it as soon as you can please :P)

Comment: yea says i need 100 rep to answer my own question in less then 8 hours. will answer later.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache2 redirect with query string escaped twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268257/apache2-redirect-with-query-string-escaped-twice)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

the way to accomplish this is via the NE (no escape) paramater.

```
RewriteRule ^something.swf$ http://www.newdomain.com/something.swf [R=302,L]
```

should in fact read

```
RewriteRule ^something.swf$ http://www.newdomain.com/something.swf [R=302,NE,L]
```

this will force mod_rewrite to leave all query string values as they are, without doing any encoding / escaping.

as easy as that :)

Comment: There may actually be a bug associated with this.  NE is a good option until you have URL encoded characters in the path segment of the URL as well.  See: http://serverfault.com/questions/331899/apache-mod-rewrite-double-encodes-query-string-on-redirect

Comment: Dropping the flag's documentation link here for future readers: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne