# PHP 5.5 I'm getting encoded url in application

Tags: apache, urlencode, php-5.5

I have currently moved a website build on Kohana 3.2 to a server with PHP 5.5 and I'm having a trouble with reading parameters as they seems to be url encoded. Is that trough php or apache config?

The example is:
**requested url:** domain.com/städlar
**application read the parameter as:** st%C3%A4dlar

mod_rewrite is on

Any advice appreciated as I would need to modify the application in many places to accept url encoded parameters.

**EDIT 1**
I've added NE flag in any RewriteRule in .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [NE,PT]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function **[urldecode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php)**

```
echo urldecode('st%C3%A4dlar');
```

Output was: `städlar`

Comment: It's in so many places in the application that it's hard to fix all the problems.

Comment: Try to change your redirect into RewriteRule, see answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6529394/2253302

Comment: See my EDIT 1, I've added NE flag to RewriteRule in .htaccess and no difference